# Correctly rendering a waveform overview (+/- volts)

Tags: math, audio, waveform, square-root

I'm trying to render a waveform, from an audio file to an image file. I've split the audio file into chunks (the number of pixels, 1 for each pixel) and then calculated the RMS value of the chunk. I've calculated the RMS value from the *absolute* value of each sample in the chunk (all samples's values are between 0-1). This has given me a nice waveform...

[image: Existing waveform]

Now I want to render a *proper* waveform. The above approach only gives the values of the sample's absolute values, so doesn't show the difference between positive and negative voltages, so no DC offsets or anything.

What would the best approach be?

Say each block is 500 samples in size, and 1 particular block has 250 positive samples, 240 negative samples and 10 samples at exactly 0. Do I calculate the negative side by negative samples only (i.e. sum of all negative samples squared, divided by 240, then the answer square-rooted), or do I divide by 500, or do some other method?

Comment: Can't you just show the RMS of positive values on the one side and RMS of negative values on the other side? You might consider some kind of density plot. Most of the samples will be around zero, so there is a high density. The edges are less likely and could therefore be visualized less densely.

Comment: Yes sorry if my OP is not clear. I suppose I'm just asking how to calculate this. Do I calculate RMS values of only negative values, or do I need to take into account the blocksize? (so would it be sum of all 240 negative values, squared, divided by 240, or sum of all 240, squared, divided by block size?)

Comment: Divided by 240. Otherwise it would be equivalent to filling the empty spaces with 0.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I was a bit confused about the power difference calculations with positive and negative values but you've cleared it up. If you put your comments as an answer, I'll mark is as answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RMS is some kind of average. So you always have to divide by the number of elements you've summed up, not by the number of elements there might be.